# perforce server, reset revision numbering for new projects

Tags: perforce

We have one project on the depot `//test` where the revision is at `50000`. After almost a year we created today a new project as a stream and the initial commit on that is `50001`. How can we reset the project revision number per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changelist numbers are global across the server; if you were to reset the changelist numbers, some of your "new" changelists would overlap with earlier ones.  If you want an entirely fresh start, start a new server instance for the new project.

Comment: I see, so the revision numbers are global per server instance? How do companies create multiple independent Projects? Spinning a new machine every time?

Comment: Most companies just don't get hung up on having the changelist numbers start at 1 for each new project.  :)  In fact, many companies that have multiple physical servers go to extra effort to centralize the changelist counter so that the change numbers can still be globally unique across all instances.

Comment: Good point, as a majority of our users are producing content, it was more aesthetics than actually an issue. From a coding perspective, a global counter makes sense. Thanks for the insight!